# Is it appropriate to follow up on an online job application?

Tags: job-search, follow-up, online

I applied for a job opening on Stackoverflow Careers about 2 weeks ago and haven't heard back from the company. Based on the job description, I'm pretty sure my skill set matches their requirements. The job opening is still available as I can see on the website. Is it appropriate to follow up on my application by sending an email or calling them on the phone? Since I applied online, I have no contact person whom I can email, so will sending an email to the general purpose address (e.g. info@company.com) make sense?

Answer (score 11):

> I'm pretty sure my skill set matches their requirements.

Unfortunately life is a giant contest. You might match their requirements but they also might have find someone who matches it better or who has a bigger motivation.

> The job opening is still available as I can see on the website.

That might mean they are not done with the recruiting process and this is why you haven't heard from them yet.

> I have no contact person whom I can email

If there is no contact adress displayed it might be for a good reason. You don't want to start stalking everyone and get a bad reputation. It has been 2 weeks, just wait and see.

Comment: And don't bank on getting any kind of reply.  As is usual, if you don't get a reply to your application, you've not been successful.

Answer (score 2):

I've applied for positions and not received responses for months. Most recently I received a text from a company I applied to more than a year ago. It is a side job kind of deal, so something I wasn't going to actively pursue.

You can play the patience game or actively find a way to contact the appropriate person with the organization. Use manta or LinkedIn to find a working phone number. Be persistent yet polite. If you really want it, go get it.

Don't think someone will be beating down your door to hire you. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of people applying for the same job every single day.

Good luck!

You might receive more specific suggestions if you let us know what kind of job this is. Specific job classifications have "typical" personality types expected to apply. I'm in sales so if I'm not aggressive when applying for a job I'm not showing my potential employer my skills in that area.